# Can't connect to tomcat7 from public ip

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694158/cant-connect-to-tomcat7-from-internet) question on stackoverflow and was recommended to ask here instead.

I've been struggling with this issue for the past two days and am hoping someone here can help me out.  I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu server 14.04 that has tomcat7 installed on it (via apt-get).  I want it accessible to computers outside my local network via my public ip address but currently I cannot connect to it that way.  I can however connect to it on my local network via 192.168.1.120.  My router (Western Digital My Net N600) is setup to forward requests on port 8080 to the VM holding tomcat7.

On my virtual machine I have iptables setup as follows:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source          destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere        anywhere                 tcp dpt:http-alt

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source          destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source          destination
```

Tomcat itself is working fine, I can connect and see the "It works!" page when I access it from 192.168.1.120:8080.  After googling some I thought maybe it was related to tomcat7 starting up using IPv6, so I set it to prefer IPv4 based on the answers [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/390840/how-does-one-get-tomcat-to-bind-to-ipv4-address) but could still not connect.

I have another service (minecraft server) hosted on a different VM with the exact same router/iptable settings (minus different port number) that DOES work.  I'm just not sure why tomcat isn't working.

I have tried different ports other than 8080 in case it was something about that particular port number but I still get nothing.  I also fired up tcpdump for port 8080, and can see traffic when it is accessed via 192.168.1.120, but no traffic when accessed via my public ip.  At this point I think I either overlooked something pretty basic or there is some setting in tomcat I need to fix/change, but I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect here is the port forwarding from your gateway is not working correct. Check that your gateway is forwarding port 8080 to your VM (192.168.1.120) .. I have done this many times and it worked fine with me ...

On your router, login to the GUI using your username and password (admin/password are the default credentials)

Go to Adwanced Settings --> Additional Features --> Port Forwarding

Give a name to your rule, Choose the Application Name as "HTTP", then set the "External Port Range" to 8080 .. Assuming that your tomcat is listening on port 8080 as well, set this to the "Internal Port Range" .. Next step is to add the server IP Address which is in your case is 192.168.1.120 .. Next step is to enable the rule. Finally, save the configuration and test the connection.

If you need a guide with screenshots, you can [click here](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8628/~/how-to-set-up-and-configure-port-forwarding-on-a-my-net-router).